# Indenting in Roxygen2

Tags: r, roxygen2

I am using `Roxygen2` to document my `R` package and wanted to know how to tell `R` to place an indent.  For example, I have the following:

```
##' @return A list with the updated parameters.
##' @return par     A matrix with k rows
##' @return weights A vector of updated weights
```

Now, I would like for there to be an indentation after `par` and after `weights` but have not been able to figure out how to do this.  I tried using latex commands like `\hspace{}` but that didn't work either for me.

Comment: Using `\verb{}` (for verbatim text) seems to work -- [like this](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/5fefc4f78e62251bb8b4ea9698115594). I'm not sure if there's a less hacky approach though.

Comment: Why? The help documents generated by your `*.Md` files will be formatted by R.... another 'hacky' way would be to edit the files in `man/` after roxygen compiles them